# How to get different regions on a pieChart proportionaly?

Tags: sql, pie-chart

```
SELECT resort.id,
        regiontext.text
from
    tablerr as resort
    inner join
        table r as region
        on resort.id = region.id
    inner join
        dbo.S_RegionText as regiontext
        on region.id = regiontext.owner_id
        where regiontext.language_id = 'de'
        order by regiontext.owner_id
```

they give differerent regions, but how can I sort them to represent them on a piechart from Primefaces?

Comment: to what then?,,,

Comment: do u have an answer for my question?

Comment: No, I just corrected the tags for you